# Set Web properties of a site using SharePoint rest api

Tags: sharepoint

From Microsoft SharePoint documentation i can get web properties of a site using this request: "http:///_api/web/" (refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn499819.aspx).

There are some properties which are R/W. 
When i try to create these R/W properties i get 200 OK response but the properties value remain unchanged.

eg. property_name - SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled.
initially it's value is True
initial get response:

```
{
    "odata.metadata": "https://druvainternal.sharepoint.com/sites/testsharepoint/subsite1copy/_api/$metadata#Edm.Boolean",
    "value": true
}
```

Then when i try to change its value using post call or merge call.
request:

```
"post"
endpoint - _api/web/SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled
body = {"value":False}
```

The response i get is:

```
{"odata.metadata":"https://druvainternal.sharepoint.com/sites/testsharepoint/subsite1copy/_api/$metadata#Edm.Boolean","value":true
}
```

whose value is still True.

Am i sending the right request? In documentations it's not mentioned about how to set these properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`Web.SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.savesiteastemplateenabled.aspx) is a property of [`Web class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.aspx), you need to construct a request to update a Web resource for that matter.

The following example shows how to *update* [`SPWeb.SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.savesiteastemplateenabled.aspx):

```
Endpoint Url:  [web url]/api/web
Method: POST 
Headers:
    "X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE"
    "If-Match":"*"
Data: 
    {"SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled":false,"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Web"}}
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim for quich reply it solved my problem. 
In headers i had to add 
"content-type" = "application/json;odata=verbose" 
or else it was giving "__metadata does not exist on SP.Web"

Comment: I've asked a similar question after attempting to use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59054606/how-can-i-update-merge-web-memberscanshare-property-value-from-the-sharepoint-re

This may help users for which this solution is not working. I'm open to suggestions on consolidating this information into your question and/or removing this comment if it is not proper.